# How can my NuGet package add another package reference at runtime based on the current runtime identifier?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm creating **multiple OS-specific NuGet packages**. Each one of them contains a fairly large native process. I can't combine them in a single NuGet package, it'll be too big. So it looks like this:

```
- MyProject.win-x86-x64
- MyProject.macos-x86-x64
- MyProject.ubuntu1804-x86-x64
- MyProject.ubuntu1804-arm64
- MyProject.debian10-x86-x64
- ...
```

I'd like to create **another netstandard2.0 package** that references the right OS-specific package based on the current OS runtime identifier, using a `.targets` file included in the `build` and `buildTransitive` package directory.

So far the best I can do is use [`$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform())`](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2468#issuecomment-451194455) which only tells if the consumer is targeting Windows, OSX or Linux. It doesn't provide the current Linux distribution.

I know it's also possible to retrieve the runtime identifier using the source code of the soon deprecated [Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions/) package, [as suggested by Dan Moseley from MS](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30213#issuecomment-510244486). However, I have no idea how I cound integrate this code into my custom `.targets` file.

Does anybody knows how I could reference the right OS-specific package in a custom `.targets` file?

Comment: When you publish the self-contained application you have to specify the runtime that can be accessed in the csproj. It allows to create some logic, for example `<When Condition=" '$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x86' "><!---include right lib---></When>`. Maybe this will help somehow.